# cannot use strings.NewReplacer("#", "o") (type *strings.Replacer) as type strings.Replacer in assignment

Tags: go, types

I am learning Go language from "Head First Go" and came across an example in 2nd chapter

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main(){
    var broken string = "Go# R#cks!"
    
    //**Below line doesn't work, getting error as shown after the program :**- 
    var replacer strings.Replacer = strings.NewReplacer("#", "o")
    
    // Whereas this line works perfectly
    replacer := strings.NewReplacer("#", "o")
    
    var fixed string = replacer.Replace(broken)
    fmt.Println(replacer.Replace(fixed))

}
```

> command-line-arguments ./hello.go:10:6: cannot use
> strings.NewReplacer("#", "o") (type *strings.Replacer) as type
> strings.Replacer in assignment

Comment: As the error states, the application attempts to assign a `*strings.Replacer` to a `strings.Replacer`.  Fix by declaring the variable as a pointer:  `var replacer *strings.Replacer = strings.NewReplacer("#", "o")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition for [`strings.NewReplacer`](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#NewReplacer) is `func NewReplacer(oldnew ...string) *Replacer`. So the function returns a [pointer](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Pointer_types) to a [Replacer](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Replacer) (see [the tour](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/1) for more on pointers).

In the statement `var replacer strings.Replacer = strings.NewReplacer("#", "o")` you are defining a variable with the type `strings.Replacer` and then trying to assign a value of type `*strings.Replacer` to it. As these are two different types the compiler reports an error. The fix is to use the correct type `var replacer *strings.Replacer = strings.NewReplacer("#", "o")` ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/edhzAm_ZW8o)).

`replacer := strings.NewReplacer("#", "o")` works OK because when using a [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) the compiler determines the type (`*strings.Replacer`) for you.

Answer (score 3):

`strings.NewReplacer("#", "o")` returns the pointer `*strings.Replacer`. So the line should be

```
var replacer *strings.Replacer = strings.NewReplacer("#", "o")
```

Link to the working program : https://play.golang.org/p/h1LOC-OUoJ2